# How to restart phone when power button does not work

Tags: power-options, nokia-8

When driving I saw a dialog that an application power control stopped. Later I realized that the phone Nokia 8 behaves strangely. I cannot go to launcher, switch application and reboot the phone. Back button works, two other buttons have no effect. Volume app and down work. I can use the power button to lock and unlock the screen. But holding it does not bring reboot options. Is there any other way how to reboot the phone?

Comment: Holding the power button pressed for maybe 10 seconds usually restarts device

Comment: Thank you. I tried it multiple times without success. This time I counted seconds and around 15 second there was a dialog that it is not possible to shut down the service. And pressing a volume up for 5 seconds will switch off it. So I continued pressing both buttons and it really helped!

Comment: Good. You cn self answer the question to help others :)